# When adding multiple images to a product, each image creates its own productId instead of belonging to the same productId

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try adding a product and upload multiple images to it, they get added and each one belongs to the same productId, but when i try to do it in the frontend, each image gets a new productId assigned to it

The issue isn't related to the backend I'm sure, so the problem lies here..
Ps: the product table has a relation to the productImages table.

```
 addProduct(): void {
  if (this.mainImageInput.nativeElement.files.length === 0) {
    console.error('No main image files provided');
    return;
  }

  if (this.productService.isUploadingProduct()) {
    console.log('Product is already being uploaded');
    return;
  }

  this.productService.setUploadingProduct(true);

  const mainImageFiles: File[] = Array.from(this.mainImageInput.nativeElement.files);

  // Upload the main image and obtain the productId
  this.uploadImage(mainImageFiles[0]).subscribe(
    (response) => {
      const productId = response.productId; // Use the productId from the main image upload

      // Log productId before passing to uploadAdditionalImages
      console.log('Before uploadAdditionalImages, productId:', productId);

      // Upload additional images associated with the same productId
      this.uploadAdditionalImages(productId);

      // Log productId after passing to uploadAdditionalImages
      console.log('After uploadAdditionalImages, productId:', productId);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error('Error adding main image:', error);
      this.productService.setUploadingProduct(false);
    }
  );
}

  
  uploadImage(imageFile: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
  
    formData.append('name', this.product.Name);
    formData.append('description', this.product.Description);
    formData.append('price', this.product.Price.toString());
    formData.append('availability', this.product.Availability.toString());
    formData.append('categoryId', this.product.CategoryId.toString());
    formData.append('brandId', this.product.BrandId.toString());
    formData.append('imageUrl', imageFile);
  
    const accessToken = 'vibesbeauty'; // Replace with your actual token
  
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
  
    return this.http.post<any>('https://vibesbeautydbapii.azurewebsites.net/api/products', formData, { headers });
  }
  
  uploadAdditionalImages(productId: number): void {
    const additionalImageFiles: File[] = Array.from(this.additionalImagesInput.nativeElement.files);
  
    let uploadedCount = 0;
  
    const handleUploadCompletion = () => {
      uploadedCount++;
  
      if (uploadedCount === additionalImageFiles.length) {
        for (const color of this.selectedColors) {
          const optionValue = color.colorCode; // Use the appropriate property of the color object
  
          this.addProductOption(productId, optionValue);
        }
  
        this.productService.setUploadingProduct(false);
  
        this.router.navigate(['/product-list']);
      }
    };
  
    for (const selectedFile of additionalImageFiles) {
      this.uploadImage(selectedFile).subscribe(
        () => {
          console.log('Additional image added successfully');
          handleUploadCompletion();
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error('Error adding additional image:', error);
          handleUploadCompletion();
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: My suspicion is that you are not unsubscribing from `uploadImage`.  If you load this component more than once without unsubscribing then it will have subscribed multiple times. This can easily happen if you view a page, go somewhere else, and then come back to the same page.